# Unable to log into Rails 5 app in Heroku with the Devise gem

Tags: heroku, devise, omniauth, actionmailer, ruby-on-rails-5

In a moment of insanity, I decided to make a Rails 5 app that uses the Devise gem and Omniauth. Everything appears to work in the development environment (though I haven't configured it to send emails from there...the cukes are passing! =D) but when I push it to Heroku and migrate (and even when I try restarting the dyno), I can't log in using a valid email and password (or via omniauth but that was expected), when I try to sign up, the account is created but no authentication email is ever sent. I can't resend the confirmation email and when I tried confirming an existing account via rails console in Heroku, I was then unable to reset the account's password using the forgotten password link on the app. No matter what I do, I receive the generic 500 error advising me to check my logs. As far as I can tell, the problem seems to be with Devise or ActionMailer as the rest of the site loads correctly.

I've tried changing my Gmail settings on the following pages:

[Display Unlock Captcha](https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha)

[Less Secure Apps (which I haven't had to use for my Rails 4 apps recently)](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps)

I've tried making various tweaks to the config files and such but so far nothing's worked.

**Heroku's logs (from when I tried to send a forgotten password email from the site)**

```
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.275213+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:232:in `block in conditional'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.275273+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:456:in `block in call'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.275332+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:456:in `call'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.275302+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:456:in `each'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.275656+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:334:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.275713+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/suppressor.rb:41:in `save'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.275774+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bundler/gems/devise-4c3838bb759e/lib/devise/models/recoverable.rb:45:in `send_reset_password_instructions'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.275362+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `__run_callbacks__'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.275509+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:202:in `within_new_transaction'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.275391+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_commit_callbacks'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.275155+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:382:in `block in make_lambda'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.275420+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:354:in `committed!'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.275451+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:87:in `commit_records'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.275684+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:318:in `save'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.276127+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `__run_callbacks__'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.276268+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.275479+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:178:in `commit_transaction'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.276857+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:262:in `dispatch'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.276997+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:46:in `serve'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.275241+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:456:in `call'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.277110+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:725:in `call'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.277194+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/omniauth-1.3.1/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.277251+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/omniauth-1.3.1/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.277279+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/omniauth-1.3.1/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.277307+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/warden-1.2.6/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.277447+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.277630+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_call_callbacks'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.277658+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.277856+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `block in tagged'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.278095+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.275538+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:232:in `transaction'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.275567+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:211:in `transaction'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.275597+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:392:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.275859+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.275927+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.276069+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:455:in `call'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.276211+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.276296+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.276800+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionview-5.0.0.1/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.277223+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/omniauth-1.3.1/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.277587+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `__run_callbacks__'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.277799+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.278008+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.278133+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.275626+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:319:in `block in save'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.275743+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bundler/gems/devise-4c3838bb759e/lib/devise/models/recoverable.rb:88:in `set_reset_password_token'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.275802+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bundler/gems/devise-4c3838bb759e/lib/devise/models/recoverable.rb:119:in `send_reset_password_instructions'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.275901+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:188:in `process_action'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.275956+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.275984+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `call'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.276012+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `call'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.276041+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.276466+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.277082+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `serve'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.277532+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in `call'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.277714+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.278038+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.276098+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:455:in `call'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.276381+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.276885+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `dispatch'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.277504+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:216:in `call'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.278267+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/server.rb:415:in `process_client'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.276155+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.276239+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:20:in `process_action'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.276437+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/searchkick-1.3.3/lib/searchkick/logging.rb:153:in `process_action'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.277025+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:39:in `block in serve'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.277391+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.277884+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.278352+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:116:in `block in spawn_thread'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.276324+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.276352+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.276913+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:32:in `serve'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.276969+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:46:in `call'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.277743+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:49:in `call'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.277828+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.277914+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `tagged'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.277980+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.278239+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/server.rb:578:in `handle_request'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.276409+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:248:in `process_action'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.277560+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:38:in `block in call'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.277686+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:36:in `call'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.277167+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/omniauth-1.3.1/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.277336+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/warden-1.2.6/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.277953+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.275829+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bundler/gems/devise-4c3838bb759e/app/controllers/devise/passwords_controller.rb:13:in `create'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.276184+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.277054+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `each'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.277139+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/omniauth-1.3.1/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.277419+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:38:in `call'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.276773+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:126:in `process'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.276828+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:190:in `dispatch'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.276941+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:16:in `block in <class:Constraints>'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.277364+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/warden-1.2.6/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.277475+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:222:in `context'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.277771+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.278067+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.278154+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.278184+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.278211+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.278324+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:116:in `call'
 2016-08-27T08:22:49.278296+00:00 app[web.1]: [0635e4c5-2a5f-467e-b067-a9906868f73d] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/server.rb:275:in `block in run'
```

**My current Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.0', '>= 5.0.0.1'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'sprockets', '>=3.0.0.beta'
#gem 'sprockets-es6'
gem 'haml'
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'devise', git: 'https://github.com/plataformatec/devise.git', branch: 'master'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'omniauth-instagram'
gem 'cancancan'
gem 'figaro'
gem 'humanize_boolean'
gem 'carrierwave', git: 'https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave'
gem 'mini_magick', '~> 3.8.0'
gem 'fog'
gem 'geocoder'
gem 'elasticsearch-model', git: 'https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-rails.git'
gem 'elasticsearch-rails', git: 'https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-rails.git'
gem 'searchkick'
gem 'cocoon'
gem 'owlcarousel-rails'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
 gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'pry-byebug', platform: :mri
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'simplecov'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', :require => false
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'rails-controller-testing'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'jasmine'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
  gem 'aws-sdk'
end
```

**config/environments/production.rb**

```
 Rails.application.configure do
   config.cache_classes = true

   config.eager_load = true

   config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
   config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

   config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

   config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier

   config.assets.compile = true

   config.log_level = :debug

   config.log_tags = [ :request_id ]

   config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

   config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
   config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { 
     host: ENV["MAILER_HOST"], #Rails.application.secrets.mailer_host, 
     from: ENV["MAILER_FROM"]#Rails.application.secrets.mailer_from
   }
   Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = ENV["MAILER_HOST"]#Rails.application.secrets.mailer_host

   config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
   config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
   config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
     address: "smtp.gmail.com",
     port: 587,
     domain: ENV["GMAIL_DOMAIN"],#Rails.application.secrets.gmail_domain,
     authentication: :plain,
     enable_starttls_auto: true,
     user_name: ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"],#Rails.application.secrets.gmail_username,
     password: ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"]#Rails.application.secrets.gmail_password
   }


   config.i18n.fallbacks = true

   config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

   config.log_formatter = ActiveSupport::Logger::Formatter.new

   # require 'syslog/logger'
   # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Syslog::Logger.new 'app-name')

   if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
     logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
     logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
     config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
   end

   config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
   Elasticsearch::Model.client = Elasticsearch::Client.new host: ENV['SEARCHBOX_SSL_URL']
 end
```

As you can see, I originally tried accessing the environment variables from the secrets file (which contained the environment variable names and referred back to Heroku's config settings but have since tried adding the variables directly to the configuration files themselves. Pushing these new changes to Heroku hasn't made much of a difference however.

**config/initializers/devise.rb**

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.mailer_sender = ENV["MAILER_FROM"]
  config.mailer = 'Devise::Mailer'
  config.parent_mailer = 'ActionMailer::Base'
  require 'devise/orm/active_record'
  config.authentication_keys = [:email]
  config.strip_whitespace_keys = [:email]
  config.http_authenticatable = false
  config.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth]
  config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 11
  config.confirmation_keys = [:email]
  config.password_length = 6..128
  config.email_regexp = /\A[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\z/
  config.reset_password_within = 6.hours
  config.sign_out_via = :delete
  config.omniauth :twitter, ENV["TWITTER_APP_ID"], ENV["TWITTER_APP_SECRET"]# Rails.application.secrets.twitter_app_id, Rails.application.secrets.twitter_app_secret
  config.omniauth :facebook, ENV["FACEBOOK_APP_ID"], ENV["FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET"]# Rails.application.secrets.facebook_app_id, Rails.application.secrets.facebook_app_secret
  config.omniauth :instagram,  ENV["INSTAGRAM_APP_ID"], ENV["INSTAGRAM_APP_SECRET"]# Rails.application.secrets.instagram_app_id, Rails.application.secrets.instagram_app_secret
end
```

**Devise routes**

```
  devise_scope :squatter do
    devise_for :squatters, controllers: { 
      sessions: "squatters/sessions",
      registrations: "squatters/registrations",
      passwords: "squatters/passwords",
      confirmations: "squatters/confirmations",
      omniauth_callbacks: "squatters/omniauth_callbacks" 
    }
  end

  resources :squatters, only: [:index, :show] do
    member do
      get :submissions_pending_approval
    end
    resources :messages, except: [:destroy, :edit, :index]
  end
```

**Devise settings for the model I'm using**

```
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, 
         :confirmable, :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: [:facebook, :twitter, :instagram]
```

Most of my devise controllers call super on the controller they inherit from. The only one I've changed is the Omniauth one. I was mostly just following a tutorial for multiple omniauth identities (sourcey.com/rails-4-omniauth-using-devise-with-twitter-facebook-and-linkedin) so this might be a red herring.

```
class Squatters::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def self.provides_callback_for(provider)
    class_eval %Q{
      def #{provider}
    @squatter = Squatter.find_for_oauth(env["omniauth.auth"], current_squatter)

    if @squatter.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @squatter, event: :authentication
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, kind: "#{provider}".capitalize) if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.#{provider}_data"] = env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_squatter_registration_url
    end
      end
    }
  end

  [:twitter, :facebook, :instagram].each do |provider|
    provides_callback_for provider
  end

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    if resource.email_verified?
      super resource
    else
      finish_signup_path(resource)
    end
  end
end
```

As mentioned earlier, I've tried running `heroku run rake db:migrate --app my_apps_name` and tried running `heroku restart --app my_apps_name`. Does anyone know if there's something that I might have missed or if this would simply indicate the presence of a bug in the latest version of Devise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My error was caused by the Searchkick gem which doesn't work with the trial version of the Searchbox addon in Heroku. I only noticed when I tried to add the secret_key_base environment variable to Devise's initializer file and started to see a reindexing error in Heroku's logs when I tried to reset a password. Commenting out the `searchkick` line in my models resolved the problem and I can now log in, &c.

Answer (score 0):

Hi did you check your config/environments folder? You have the production.rb and development.rb files there. When you installed devise, you are made to include this `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }` in your development.rb file, this is for sending password confirmation link and reset password link. 
Did you include this same in your production.rb file? If you are hosting on heroku, it should be the link of your app.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I 've already included the production.rb file in my question (there's a slight typo in the label in fairness, which I'll change in a minute). My production.rb file contains the configuration settings for gmail and actionmailer and I've added the relevant environment variables to Heroku. I've set the site's URL as the host. I'm still getting a 500 error however.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this config in your heroku app.

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host =>     'myapp.herokuapp.com' }  
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp  
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true  
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false  
config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"  
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {  
  address: "smtp.gmail.com",
  port: 587,
  domain: "myapp.herokuapp.com",
  authentication: "plain",
  enable_starttls_auto: true,
  user_name: ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"],
  password: ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"]
}
```

Comment: I've removed the `:from` key-value pair from `default_url_options`, added a default charset and set authentication to `"plain"` (it was `:plain` before that), pushed to heroku and restarted the dyno. I still receive the error message I posted earlier when I click the forgotten password link on my app.